# I have troubles installing several app using docker compose

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

For my personnal knowledge I want set up my server on docker (using docker compose).
And I have some troubles setting up several app (probem comes from the ports).

I have a completly clean debian 8 server.
I created 2 repositories one for nextcloud the other one for bitwarden
I started first next cloud everythings is fine so after that I launch bitwarden and I have an error because I'm using the same port. But because I want to use letsencrypt for both and an https web site how am I suppose to configure the ports and the reverse proxy.

## this one is for nextcloud

```
version: '3' 

services:

  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true"
    container_name: nextcloud-proxy
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:rw
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nextcloud-letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - proxy
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    restart: unless-stopped

  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: nextcloud-mariadb
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysql
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  app:
    image: nextcloud:latest
    container_name: nextcloud-app
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    depends_on:
      - letsencrypt
      - proxy
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
      - ./app/config:/var/www/html/config
      - ./app/custom_apps:/var/www/html/custom_apps
      - ./app/data:/var/www/html/data
      - ./app/themes:/var/www/html/themes
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=nextcloud.YOUR-DOMAIN
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=nextcloud.YOUR-DOMAIN
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=YOUR-EMAIL
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

networks:
  nextcloud_network:
```

## this one is for bitwarden

```
version: "3"

services:
  bitwarden:
    image: bitwardenrs/server
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./bw-data:/data
    environment:
      WEBSOCKET_ENABLED: "true" 
      SIGNUPS_ALLOWED: "true" 

  caddy:
    image: abiosoft/caddy
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./Caddyfile:/etc/Caddyfile:ro
      - caddycerts:/root/.caddy
    ports:
      - 80:80 # needed for Let's Encrypt
      - 443:443
    environment:
      ACME_AGREE: "true" 
      DOMAIN: "bitwarden.example.org"  
      EMAIL: "bitwarden@example.org"  
volumes:
  caddycerts:
```

The error is :

> Blockquote ERROR: for root_caddy_1  Cannot start service caddy: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint root_caddy_1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx : Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated

Comment: You should start everything on the same network + a new proxy server (NGINX). You can remove all port mappings to 80 and 443 and instead configure subdomains in the new proxy server. The proxy server will be the only one listening to 80 and 443 ports and based on the subdomain proxy forward to the respective container. Would that be an option?

Comment: Thanks, Yes that can be a good option have you any clues how to set up that proxy server (git hub progect or tuto online) ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I will detail here the solution with multiple subdomains.

First of all the easiest solution for now is to put all the services in the same docker-compose file. If not you would have to create a network and declare that as external network in each docker-compose.yml.

Next remove the ports declaration for the `proxy` and `caddy` containers (to free up ports 80 and 443 on the host).

Create a new service and add it to the same docker-compose.yml:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
    - ./subdomains_conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```

Next create a folder `subdomanins_conf` and in it a file `default.conf` with the contents something similar to:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name first.domain.com;

  location {
    proxy_pass http://proxy:80;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name second.domain.com;

  location {
    proxy_pass http://caddy:80;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
  }

}
```

You need to replace the values for `server_name` with your actual domain names. The configuration for SSL is similar.

You can test this setup locally by pointing the 2 domains to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts. Remember that all the services should be defined in the same docker-compose.yml or you need to create a network and specify it in each docker-compose.yml otherwise the containers will not see each other.

Comment: Thanks it's seems to work for the http
I made that for the https
```conf
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name nextcloud.maximiliemoraud.fr;

  location {
    proxy_pass https://proxy:443;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $https_host;
  }
}
```
but that doesn't work have you any clues ?

Comment: nginx doesn't really support ssl forwarding and that is also because you don't really need it. Even in your case I don't think you really need it. You can receive trafic on 443 and then redirect it to port 80 of the container. You just need to apply all your certificates in the nginx container. So your configuration could be: `conf server { listen 443 ssl http2; listen [::]:443 ssl http2; server_name nextcloud.maximiliemoraud.fr; location { proxy_pass https://proxy:80; proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; proxy_set_header HOST $https_host; } }`

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to manage this problem using reverse proxy with traefik
https://docs.traefik.io/